# How to replace special text in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There is one `string` like this: `'xxxxxxx#code#xxxxxxxx'`, I want to replace the code.

Comment: why? y u do this? Where's your code?

Comment: @AmitJoki I need send the voucher code to users, the email content is static, but I need to add one dynamic code to the content

Comment: So... regex? Simple replace? What's the actual issue you're facing? What are you doing that isn't working?

Comment: Ok, I just want to ask how to write the regex? 'xxxxxxx#code#xxxxxxxx'.gsub(/?/, '1234') =>  'xxxxxxx1234xxxxxxxx'

Comment: Kind of depends on what `"code"` can actually be, no? If it's just the string literal "code" it's beyond trivial. Without providing any details there's little way to answer the question. If it's just "the stuff between `#` characters then it's simple regex, and you'd be better served by learning something about regexes.

Comment: Please provide input and output examples to make answering this question more efficient. Based on the current question there are a plethora of acceptable answers but not all of them may apply to your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex and `string.gsub()`

```
2.0.0-p643 :004 > "xxxxxxx#code#xxxxxxxx".gsub(/\#code#/i, "#NEWCODE#")
=> "xxxxxxx#NEWCODE#xxxxxxxx"
```